# Linear regression (regress) discrepancy with polynomial fit (polyfit)

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, curve-fitting, least-squares, polynomials

I have some data which comes from a linear function (`y=mx+c`) where `m=4, c=1` (so: `y=4x+1`).

When I try to get back the coefficients using `regress`, I'm getting an R<sup>2</sup><1 and a seemingly random `m` value:

```
x = [1 2 3 4]
y = [5 9 13 17]
[m,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(y',x');

%{
>> R = stats(1) % Coefficient of determination
R =
     1
>> m % Linear function coefficients
m = 
     4.333333333333333
%}
```

Whereas `polyfit` does this correctly:

```
P = polyfit(x,y,1);

%{
>> P(1)
ans =
    4.000000000000000
>> P(2)
ans =
    1.000000000000000
%}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is not following the documentation or [`regress`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) which states that:

> `b = regress(y,X)` returns a vector `b` of coefficient estimates for a multiple linear regression of the responses in vector `y` on the predictors in matrix `X`. **The matrix `X` must include a column of ones**.

If we include a column of ones in the 2<sup>nd</sup> input, we get the desired result:

```matlab
x = [1 2 3 4].';
y = [5 9 13 17].';
[m,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(y,[ones(size(x)) x]);

%{
Results:
m =
    1.0000
    4.0000
bint =
    1.0000    1.0000
    4.0000    4.0000
r =
   1.0e-14 *
    0.1776
    0.1776
    0.1776
         0
rint =
   1.0e-13 *
    0.0178    0.0178
   -0.2190    0.2545
   -0.2190    0.2545
   -0.2141    0.2141
stats =
   1.0e+31 *
    0.0000    1.6902    0.0000    0.0000
%}
```

Comment: thanks, just worked this one out myself, thanks for answering